# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once when using MVC controller views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I get the error above when I set my templateUrl, .cshtml, as controller view in asp mvc. My code is below:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Default", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/ViewAccountPartial.html",
            controller: "viewAccountController"
        })
        .when("/EditAccount", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/EditAccountPartial.html", <=== NO PROBLEM WITH THIS
            controller: "editAccountController"
        })
        .when("/ViewVisitors", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/ViewVisitorsPartial.html", <=== NO PROBLEM WITH THIS
            controller: "viewVisitorController"
        })
        .when("/ViewItineraries", {
            templateUrl: "/Itinerary/ViewItineraries",  <===== Controller/Action [THIS CAUSES THE ENDLESS LOOP]
            controller: 'viewItineraryController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Default" });
}])
```

**asp mvc controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ViewItineraries")]
public ActionResult ViewItineraries()
{
    return View("ViewItineraries");
}
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Did u see that template url "Itinerary/ViewItineraries" is missing HTML at the end. "Itinerary/ViewItineraries.html". is this a typo ?

Comment: "Itinerary" is the name of the Controller and the "ViewItineraries" is the name of the Method that returns a View which is a ".cshtml". I am using angularjs in ASP MVC

Answer (score 1):

For those who may be curious, this is how I resolved the issue. Make sure that you are authorize if it has the "Authorize annotation" in your ASP Controller and return a "partial" view if you need to place the html tags in the `ng-view` directive.

Comment: If you have the time, it's better to change partial views to json data while using angular or any other javascript frameworks.

Comment: Hmmm... Good lesson for me. Though I haven't tried that yet.